# Enable WPFApplication access to existing WCF RIA Services

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-toolkit

I have a big (too big for me, about 50k line) Silverlight application, written by an ex-colleague. It is written really (really really) badly so I'm not going to change/touch almost nothing.

I'd like to easily enable access to his WCF RIA Services from a WFC command line app. There's almost 30 domain service class in the web part of SL app.

I installed the SL and WCF-RIA toolkits.
I've added those lines in the web.config but the compiler doesn't recognize the `<domainServices>`.

```
<domainServices>
  <endpoints>
    <add name="OData" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ODataEndpointFactory, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="Soap" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </endpoints>
</domainServices>
```

From the new command line app I can't see any services in my solution. 
Any Idea of what I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by the "compiler" ?
If you're referring to visual studio intellisense that underline your tags, it's not the problem it's just a xsd "problem".

How are you trying to access your to your endpoint from the console app ?

Comment: Yeah, i meant the intellisense. 
I'm trying to access adding a service reference. It's the right way?

Comment: yep it is just pay attention at the address and don't rely on the service auto discover features of VS. I'm going to write it as answer and add some links

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem rely on the way you try to add the service reference: auto discover don't work and you don't have an .svc file. You should use something like http://[hostname]/[namespacename]-[classname].svc but I recommend to have a look at these articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2009/11/23/understanding-the-wcf-in-wcf-ria-services.aspx and
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/11/22/ria-services-a-domainservice-is-a-wcf-service-add-service-reference.aspx

that give a detailed insghts